# How to Create Dataset for Tensorflow with Images and Labels

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset, classification, image-classification

I’d like to create a dataset from images in a special folder. Next I’d like to classify them using tensorflow according to the scheme from the dataset.

Is there any quick and efficient way to create a dataset from images and labels?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague but here is what I think you mean and you can solve your problem.

I guess you have some images, who belong to certain classes. The images of the same class are in the same folder. Like so:

```
images/
   cats/
       img_0.png
       img_1.png
       img_2.png
       ...
   dogs/
       img_0.png
       img_1.png
       img_2.png
       ...
```

You now want a dataset where the x-values are the images and the y-values are the classes.

As described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images#load_using_keraspreprocessing) you can use

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
```

to load your data. In the example I've given the variable for `data_dir` should hold the value `"images"`. This is a fast and convenient way to load data in TensorFlow. I recommend to click on the link I provided to see the full tutorial on loading data into TensorFlow.